# Why are there sometimes stack frames with a call to line 1 when I debug in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm not sure if this is a bug in eclipse or if it intentional but I just haven't figured out why it's happening. Every now and then when I step through a program, stepping into a method causes the call pointer (blue arrow that marks the execution line) to point to line one of the class. Usually there's no code on line one, as it's the start of a muli-line comment that describes the file.

The only way to proceed to the next method (that was originally intended) from this point is with the step into button. Stepping over returns to the previous stack frame. In the debug view, the method name is listed twice; one marked at line 1 and the second marked at the appropriate line. The stack trace looks something like this:

```
...
ClassX.someMethod(args...), line 68
ClassX.someMethod(args...), line 1
ClassY.callSomeMethod(args...), line 265
ClassZ.doStuff(args...), line 23
...
```

Is this supposed to be a helpful feature? Am I missing the reason why this happens entirely (I'm trying to think of what could be happening, but I see no correlation with class hierarchies, or specific design patterns)?

(aside: tagging Java since it might be due to mechanics of the language causing eclipse to behave this way)

Comment: It happens when your class has code to initialize it that is triggered on some other function call.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what you mean. Could you add an example to explain it?